# could not find or load main class in package

Tags: java, package

I try to understand the concept of packages, why do I get this error?

```
->javac B.java
->java B
Error: Could not find or load main class B
```

Class B:

```
package a0;

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I work under Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Where are you compiling and running from?

Comment: The directory the .java file is in.

Comment: There is an answer **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean**

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the B.class must be in a folder named like the package itself, and executed via `java a0.B`.